# Getting int object is not iterable error

Tags: python, random, pyautogui

so I'm using pyautogui to type in a textbox and I'm trying to type a random integer something like this.

```
    import pyautogui
    import random
    pyautogui.typewrite(random.randint(0, 1000))
```

but I'm getting a 'int object is not iterable' error.
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You forgot a closing bracket).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, certainly that's a problem with the code shared here. It's likely that the closing bracket is present in his original code, however, or else OP would be getting `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` rather than `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. Probably just a transcription error while writing the question.

Comment: Yea I closed the bracket in the orginal code just a typo on here my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typewrite` takes a string (or list of strings), not an integer.

```
pyautogui.typewrite(str(random.randint(0, 1000)))
```